# Ruby: Not able to access method of one module from another module

Tags: ruby

I am learning ruby. for learning purpose i have written a code with nested modules as show below. my task is to print oupupt "IN FIRST A" from module C. i tried Object::A::A.show and ::A::A.show but it is printing output "in second A".  i also tried A::A.show but it is giving error as uninitialized constant. please help in understanding why it is printing "in second A" and what i need to do to printer "IN FIRST A" output

```
module A

  def self.show
    puts "in outer A"
  end

  module A
    def self.show
        puts "IN FIRST A"
    end
  end

  module A
    def self.show
        puts "in second A"
    end
  end

  module C

    def self.show
       puts "in Third A"
    end
    Object::A::A.show
  end

end
```

Comment: indentation has a purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider this example (which is completely analogous):

> ```
> a = 3
> b = 4
> b = 5
> puts b
> # 5
> ```
>
> How do I display `4`?

Your first method is `::A::show`. Your second and third are *both* `::A::A::show`. Thus, your third definition is *overwriting* your second one, and you only have two methods. The method that prints `"IN FIRST A"`, thus, does not exist after the third `def` has run. The only way to execute that method is to run it in between the second and third definition, when it's defined but not overwritten yet.

(`::A::A::show` can also be written `::A::A.show`, as you did, with no change in meaning.)

Comment: @Stefan: Overriding is when you provide a new definition in a subclass that takes priority over a more general method in an ancestor; the original method still exists, and can be accessed on the ancestor, or in descendants where it wasn't overridden. I wrote "overwriting", and meant it: the original method here is replaced by a newly defined one, and the old one is gone.

Comment: The Ruby [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Overriding) uses the term "overriding" for redefining a method, although no inheritance is involved. And the original method is not necessarily gone. You can use `alias` (or `alias_method` / `method`) to store the method prior to redefining it.

Comment: @Stefan: It appears you are right regarding the term used in the docs, although I would argue the term is used incorrectly. [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html), [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype), [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html), [Wikipedia (general)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding)... and even [all other mentions I found for Ruby](http://google.com/search?q=ruby+override) use "overriding" for subclasses only, and usually "redefining" for

Comment: ... what is happening here. That said, "overwriting" is intuitively graspable. Even if "overriding" is used in docs, it is potentially confusing, given how it is definitely not the common usage of this word in the OO world. (As for aliasing, yes, if you aliased it it is not gone, you just destroyed one reference to it.)

Comment: I stand corrected, "overwriting" is a much more appropriate term when redefining a method this way.